# ATLAS/GLOBE both say uptime is 8hrs 30mins but 3-day uptime graph is 100%. Why the inconsistency?

Tags: relays, atlas, error

Both ATLAS and GLOBE say my node has been up for only 8 hours 30 minutes but the 3-day graph of uptime indictaes no interruption in that period (i.e. 100% uptime).

When I run 'arm' that indicates Tor has been running for considerably longer than 3 days.

What is ATLAS/GLOBE trying to say when it presents apparently inconsistent data about a node?

**UPDATE** 2 October: My broadband supplier uses dynamic IP address allocation. For reasons I cannot yet understand, it changes the allocated IP address of the host running Tor every so often. The running Tor process recognises this change and rebuilds its descriptor. GLOBE eventually picks up that the IP address of my node has changed and reflects the new uptime for the node in its headlines. However it does not upgrade the graph of uptime. Not sure whether that is deliberate or a bug. The 'arm' monitor shows the changed IP address but does not change the uptime. That seems to be a bug too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "uptime" here means different things. 8h 30 minutes is how long the node has been continuously up, without restarts or, it looks like, IP address changes. 100% is the percentage of time the node has been listed as up in the Tor directory. If you restart your node, it will reset the continuous uptime duration, but if it comes back quickly enough, it won't affect the uptime percentage.